# Angular 1/ui-router - execute function into data object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I want to run a method that returns a string into `data` object.

For example if the result returned by the method is: "Richard Stallman" I want that on my controller with: this. `$state.current.data.title` equal to "Richard Stallman"
as if I simply did :

```
  data: {
    title: "Richard Stallman"
  }
```

My state :

```
.state({
  name: 'agent.production.myiad.project.detail.edit.headers.overlay.comment',
  url: '/comment',
  data: {
    title: (project, IadProjectUtilService) => {
            IadProjectUtilService.getProjectName(project) 
      }
  },
  component: 'iadAgentMyIadComment'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is generally solved by a `resolve` block.

```
.state({
  name: 'agent.production.myiad.project.detail.edit.headers.overlay.comment',
  url: '/comment',
  resolve: {
    title: (project, IadProjectUtilService) => {
            IadProjectUtilService.getProjectName(project) 
      }
  },
  component: 'iadAgentMyIadComment'
});
```

...

uirouter will wait for the promise returned by `IadProjectUtilService.getProjectName(project)` and then bind it to the component's `title` binding.

```
.component('iadAgentMyIadComment', {
  bindings: { title: '<' },
  controller: IadAgentMyIadCommentController,
});
```

Here is a guide on routing to components: https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component#resolve-bindings